# dataset value substition not yielding expected result

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have the following two dataframes in R

```r
df <- data.frame("Z_Frequency" = c(5,10,15,20,25), 
                 "Z_Slope2"=c(0,.7, -0.5,0,.7))

df24 <- data.frame("Z_Frequency" = seq(from = min(df$Z_Frequency), 
                                       to = max(df$Z_Frequency), by = 1))
```

I am populating the values of `df24$Z_SSLOPE` column by comparing the value of `df24$Z_Frequency` and `df$Z_Frequency`: if the value of `df24$Z_Frequency` is identical to the of `df$Z_Frequency`, the `df24$Z_SSLOPE` column value will be copied from `df$Z_Slope2`.
I have written the following code-loop for the same.

```r
df24$Z_SSLOPE <- 0

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) { 
  for (j in 1:nrow(df24)) { 
    if(df24$Z_Frequency[j] == df$Z_Frequency[i]) { 
      df24$Z_SSLOPE[j] <- df$Z_Slope2[i]
    } else 
    if(df24$Z_Frequency[j] > df$Z_Frequency[i] & df24$Z_Frequency[j] < df$Z_Frequency[i+1]) {
      df24$Z_SSLOPE[j] = df$Z_Slope2[df24$Z_Frequency[j] > df$Z_Frequency[i] & 
    df24$Z_Frequency[j] < df$Z_Frequency[i+1]]
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output is as follows

```
     Z_Frequency Z_SSLOPE
1            5      0.0
2            6      0.7
3            7      0.7
4            8      0.7
5            9      0.7
6           10      0.7
7           11     -0.5
8           12     -0.5
9           13     -0.5
10          14     -0.5
11          15     -0.5
12          16      0.0
13          17      0.0
14          18      0.0
15          19      0.0
16          20      0.0
17          21      0.7
18          22      0.7
19          23      0.7
20          24      0.7
21          25      0.7
```

In case `df24$Z_Frequency` values don't find a match in `df$Z_Frequency`, the values are filled by the next available match of `df24$Z_Frequency`. I am getting the following output.

```
     Z_Frequency     Z_SSLOPE
 1            5      0.0
 2            6      0.0
 3            7      0.0
 4            8      0.0
 5            9      0.0
 6           10      0.7
 7           11      0.0
 8           12      0.0
 9           13      0.0
 10          14      0.0
 11          15     -0.5
 12          16      0.0
 13          17      0.0
 14          18      0.0
 15          19      0.0
 16          20      0.0
 17          21      0.0
 18          22      0.0
 19          23      0.0
 20          24      0.0
 21          25      0.7
```

The first part of the if statement works. However, I am unable to spot the error in the else part of the if statement. I request someone's help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a problem with `dplyr`, we can `dplyr::left_join` then `tidyr::fill` the gap backwards

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df24 %>% 
 left_join(df) %>% 
 fill(Z_Slope2,.direction = 'up')
```

Comment: Is the left join similar to an sql join

Comment: It's the same concept as far as I know. But to be sure please check `?left_join` or `help(left_join)`